# Custom calendar cannot selecting date in Samsung galaxy s5

Tags: android

My application is working fine in all devices including samsung galaxy s4, it has a custom calendar but if i try to select date in Samsung galaxy S5 its not selecting, nothing happens.

Please provide suggestions to make it working with samsung galaxy s5.

I am using this in menifest to set target level

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DatePicker instead. Its a layout just like button, in android. And easy to use too.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i can't use datepicker in my application, i make it using grid layout  and its custome. its working fine in all devices but on samsung galaxy s5 its not working,  DO you have some suggestions regarding this